# Update html video based on two select boxes, loads but doesn't play the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I'm new to javascript/jquery programming, and I know this should be easy, and although I'm close, I ultimately stumped (after much searching on SO and Google).

I have a simple web page with an html form consisting of two select boxes, a submit button, and a video.  Basically, the user makes a selection from each select box (selecting the year and the watershed), then clicks the "play" button, and a video plays.

Here's a [link](http://167.88.113.65/sfr/index.html).

**Problem**:

When I make a selection from each select box and click the submit button, I see a brief glimpse of the video, then everything resets... the select boxes reset to the default, and the video is quickly replaced by the "poster" image.

Here's the html for the form, select boxes, submit button, and video:

```
<section class="select-bar">
    <form>
        <select id="select-year" name="select-year">
            <option value="None">Select a year</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
        </select>
        <select id="select-basin" name="select-basin">
            <option value="assets/png/display.png">Select a basin</option>
            <option value="Asotin">Asotin</option>
            <option value="Entiat">Entiat</option>
            <option value="JohnDay">John Day</option>
            <option value="Lemhi">Lemhi</option>
            <option value="Methow">Methow</option>
            <option value="SouthForkSalmon">South Fork Salmon</option>
            <option value="Tucannon">Tucannon</option>
            <option value="UpperGrandeRonde">Upper Grande Ronde</option>
            <option value="Wenatchee">Wenatchee</option>
        </select>
        <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Play</button>
    </form>
</section>
<section class="vid-section">
    <video id="vid" width=600 poster="assets/png/display.png" controls>
        <source id="mp4vid" src="#" type="video/mp4" />
</section>
```

Here's the Jquery code that switches the video based on the values from the select boxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var videoID = 'vid';
        var sourceID = 'mp4vid';
        $('#submit-button').click(function(){
            var yr = $('#select-year').val();
            var basin = $('#select-basin').val();
            var newsrc = 'assets/mp4/' + basin + yr + '.mp4';
            $('#' + sourceID).attr('src', newsrc);
            $('#' + videoID).get(0).load();
            $('#' + videoID).get(0).play();  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Anything I'm obviously doing wrong here?

**Update on 10/23/2015**: Because I'm getting a "No video with supported format and MIME type found" error in the display area of the video, I thought it might be an issue with the video encoding, so I tried pointing towards WebM video files instead, but I still am having the same problem.

Comment: Are you blocking the forms default action? Hitting a submit button in a form will cause it to post.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by blocking.   The form isn't set up to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `e.preventDefault()` inside your submit-button binding

```
    $('#submit-button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var yr = $('#select-year').val();
        var basin = $('#select-basin').val();
        var newsrc = 'assets/webm/' + basin + yr + '.webm';
        $('#' + sourceID).attr('src', newsrc);
        $('#' + videoID).get(0).load();
        $('#' + videoID).get(0).play();  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but now I don't even see the brief glimpse of the video (which I assume is the "load").  The select boxes just go back to default, no video is played.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the issue.  I didn't have the submit button click function listening to anything:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
```

so I just made sure the function was listening for an event, i.e.:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(event) {
```